# How do I get #3 THHN wire from the attic to the panel if the max hole in the top plate is 1.25"?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I'm pulling 100A service from my main panel to a detached Workshop (about 90 feet).  I'm required to use 1 1/4 in conduit which has an exterior diameter of 1.625".  The max hole I can drill in a 2x4 top plate is 1.25".  How can I get #3 THHN through the wall to the panel? I understand that the conduit must be continuous for the entire run from panel to sub panel.

Comment: why do you think max hole is 1.25" in top plate?

Comment: Are you extending the 40% rule for studs to plates?  Plates can usually have larger holes and there are steel plates to reinforce them them for bigger holes.

Comment: Guess where they put 3 inch drain pipes hidden in the 2x4 walls.

Comment: If your main panel is in a utility space, running conduit on the surface is a fine way to avoid any holes in framing. Tends to tick off the appearance police if it's in the living room, though. A soffit is another way to avoid the framing just at the top of the wall, while concealing the pipe. You should reconsider the copper implied by 100A and 3AWG, it will save you **a lot of money** to use 1 AWG aluminum wiring, and the terminals you'll attach to at both ends are aluminum.

Comment: Lose 10A and save even more, in the same size conduit, with 2-2-2-4 at 90A (breaker at the feed end - the sub-panel can and probably should be a 200A unit, just to get adequate spaces.) That particular aluminum cable is at a price sweet spot, for arcane economic reasons. If you use EMT conduit, the OD for 1-1/4" is only 1.510

Comment: Or if using EMT 3@#3 & 1@#8 fits in 1", which would fit 1.25 hole if you're stuck on that size hole.

Answer (score 7):

IRC <s>[602.6.1](https://inspectapedia.com/structure/Wood-Joist-Stud-Boring-Notching-Codes.php)</s> moved to [602.2.3.1](https://up.codes/viewer/florida/fl-residential-code-2014/chapter/6/wall-construction#R602.2.3.1) states:

> When piping or ductwork is placed in or partly in an exterior wall or
> interior load-bearingwall, necessitating cutting, drilling or notching
> of the top plate by more than 50 percent of its width, a galvanized
> metal tie of not less than 0.054 inches thick (1.37mm) (16ga) and 1-1/2
> inches (38mm) wide shall be fastened to each plate across and to each
> side of the opening with not less than eight 16d nails at each side or
> equivalent. See Figure R602.6.1.
>
> Exception: When the entire side of the wall with the notch or cut is
> covered by wood structural panel sheathing

So that means that the maximum hole you can drill in a top plate is NOT limited to 1.25"

A plate is not a stud.

You want the reenforcing plates there as nail protection plates anyway.

Answer (score 5):

A simple question, but experience tells me there *might* be several misconceptions there.  So please indulge my guesses as they could save you some coin.

#1 it's a false presumption that copper should be used for heavy feeder. This is pointless.  Aluminum is proven safe at large sizes, and the lugs it'll be landing on are made of aluminum. What really decides safety is use of a torque wrench - that's why AL heavy feeders have always been safe and why 1970s era small branch circuit wiring failed (nobody used a torque screwdriver on that back then).

#2 There are other types of conduit than PVC.  When space is at a premium, EMT metal conduit should be used as it has the thinnest wall by far.  This is much better for DIYers, too - since nothing is glued, it all comes apart like an Erector Set, so you don't have to double down on mistakes - you can disassemble and correct with no wasted material except maybe a bit of pipe.

#3 We haven't discussed your setup, but most novices fixate on the feeder size having *exactly the same ampacity* as the absolute max amp rating (redline) of the panel. Not at all; I'm reluctant to run panels at redline honestly. I'd prefer a 125-200A panel for a 100A feeder.

It's also an error to think there's any economy to scrimping on panel spaces. I'm probably at a 200A panel because I'm selecting a 24-30 space panel, because of experience with just how much stuff a 90-100A feeder can power, and knowing that pain of running out of spaces for future projects.  Spaces are cheap. Regrets are expensive.

Another novice whoops is to fixate on a nice, round number like "100A" which seems popular (even though it makes no difference to the usage), **and then, letting that drive up the cost of the project**.

So, to wrap all this up, and notwithstanding what Ecnerwal says about diameters not being a problem...  If you can be a player at 90A, then it all comes together nicely.  Any panel rated 100A or more.  1" EMT to go through the top plate, so our hole is < 1-1/4".  Inside the EMT we can *just* fit three 2 AWG aluminum (a very popular size, easy to procure) and a #8 copper ground wire. (easier if it's bare.)

The concession to 90A is important because 100A requires #1 aluminum, which won't quite fit in 1" EMT.

Also note that if the conduit section is less than 24" long, you can push conduit fill up to 60% - so running 1-1/4" and stepping down to 1" for that short bit is a possible play. Then you could use #1 aluminum or even possibly PVC.

Normally EMT doesn't require a ground *wire* at all, but I assume you're going to transition to some other type of conduit once you clear that obstacle. Also, EMT can't go underground.

By the way, aluminum wire is more compact than copper wire because the higher ductility of the new AA-8000 alloys permits "compact stranded" - where the strands are shaped to be more hexagonal.  It also bends more easily, being a lighter metal.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your thoughtful and detailed responses.  After reading other posts that recommended calling the electrical inspector, I did.  I already bought the #3 THHN so I obviously didn't have enough information when I did that.  I asked the electrical inspector if I could connect wire that can be run through the wall in a junction box in the attic.  He recommended connecting #2 SER and then routing that through the top plate and into the box from behind the wall.  I'm using insulated lugs for the connections (those are expensive!).  I've got the conduit run and secured from the LB box on the wall to the junction box (4 11/6 box was the minimum size, I went with a 6x6 box for ease).  Pulling wire tomorrow.  Thank you all again for your responses to this and other posts.  You are providing knowledge and skills to the DIY community.